Which scripture should I read to know more about Mother Kali?
I am fascinated by 10 Mahavidya forms of omnipotent mother Jagad-Amba and out of 10, I am captivated, enchanted, and bewitched by the form of Mother Kali. Is there any Granth which explicitly talks about Mother Kali?

Devi mahatyam, Kalika Puran. Etc
